# Existe alguma forma de incluir o cabeçalho do Wordpress em uma pagina externa que eu criei?

Tags: php, wordpress

Quando eu crio uma pasta com o index dentro dos meus arquivos do site (onde esta instalado o wordpress) aparece a pagina em branco e da pra colocar coisas e estilizar normalmente, mas será que tem como eu incluir o meu cabeçalho do tema nessa pagina?

Sei que é uma duvida boba, mas tem como eu fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você vai ter mais trabalho fazendo isso do que só fazendo uma página no Wordpress e definindo ela como inicial. Por que o WP faz várias coisas antes de incluir o cabeçalho no site (conecta no banco, busca os menus e tal). Para definir uma página do WP como página inicial:

- Crie uma página no Wordpress em Pages > Add new (Páginas > Adicionar nova)
- Defina como página inicial em Admin > Settings > Reading (Configurações > Leitura). No primeiro campo, é só marcar A static page (uma página estática) e depois escolher sua página inicial na caixinha.

Você pode escrever o HTML todo da página ao criá-la.